# How to upload a file using a simple jquery-ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am searching for a **simple** client-side script to upload a file using ajax. 
Searching for the web for this script only brought up a lot of plugins with multi-features. I don't need multi-feautres - just to be able to upload it as simple as possible using ajax

Is it possible to write something simple as:

```
$.get('server/upload.php?file = ' + $('#uploadInput').val(), function(data) {
   $('.result').html(data);    
 });
```

If it is possible - how should I write it right (`$('#uploadInput').val()` won't give me the right directory path - so what do I need to do to pass the location using Ajax).

aside from that - in order to get drag&drop for files - Is there a simple script for that or do I need to use plugin (and is there a really tiny and simple one without multi-features)

Comment: The words 'simple', 'ajax', and 'upload' are not words that go well together I'm afraid. There is no quick way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use AJAX to upload files (unless the clients browsers supports the HTML 5  element, which allows access to the file object.).

Your solution is to fake it

*create a form element*

```
<form id="myForm" action="upload.php" method="POST" target="results_frame">
  <input name="fileUpload" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

We set the target of the frame for 'results_frame', we'll define it after the form in the HTML as an empty iframe.

```
<iframe id="results_frame" name="results_frame" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Then, in the backend in your php file you can capture the file as -

```
$_FILE['file']['param']; //where param accepts multiple values
//such as name, type, size, error, and tmp_name
```

Once you've done your manipulating with the file, you can make an echo whatever information you want, including refreshing the initial form at this point.

Comment: See my answer, I think it's pretty clear what I mean is correct. Your answer, does it contain ajax? Or am I missing something.

Comment: I've been using this for ages, tell me again this is not pure ajax/jQuery: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this using some HTML5 features such as the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) (take a look at the *Example: Uploading a user-selected file* section in this article).

But if you want cross browser solution I would recommend you using a client side upload plugin. For example the [jQuery form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) plugin is quite easy to setup. [Valums Ajax upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) is also very nice. It provides many functionalities such as drag and drop and upload progress but if you don't care about them, they can be easily turned off.

Comment: I don't understand why it can't be simple. I can do it using a php file. so why can't I do it with the same php file but with an ajax call that sends it the parameters?

Comment: @Alon, because in order to upload a file to the server you need to be able to access its contents. And for very obvious reasons you cannot access file contents on the client computer using javascript. Actually the HTML5 File API allows you to do that assuming the user already selected a file in a file input. Also I don't see anything complicated in using a plugin that's designed for this task.

Answer (score 1):

On modern browsers you can use the new xhr2 (see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) to perform a neat AJAX file upload ... including progress bar. I don't really know if this has already been embedded into the latest jQuery. Maybe someone else can shed some light on that.

Answer (score 0):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is another great solution for ajax upload. Its

- extremely easy to setup,
- very stylish, and
- **cross broswer**.

See [demos](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/)

Comment: Download button leads to Paypal donate procedure? "Nice"!

Comment: @AleksandrMakov, Oh It used to be a free product. Just because you have to pay for it, doesn't disproves my point in answer. 

And they are hard working developers, not a freeloader like you they deserve some donation now. It has been free for so many years now. Pay some respect to the developer

Comment: hm, where did I "disprove" your point? Hey, Starx, here's your beer! Oh, now when you hold that cold bottle — pay please, I deserved it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a ajax uploader that works in all moderns browsers, you should check out some jQuery plugins. Check out this article for example: http://www.tutorialchip.com/jquery/9-powerful-jquery-file-upload-plugins/ .

What you suggested in your first post will not work. Even if you grab the content from the form, you can't put the information in GET. URLs can maximum be 2000 (?) characters long, so uploading a bigger file will cause the upload to crash. You need to send this using POST.

Btw, I've had some good experience with this plugin: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ . It is pretty simple, so you can customize it like you want (with some basic jQuery/js experience).

Hope it helps.